# USB missile launcher on Linux

Tags: python, usb

I came across a page on Hacking the Kinect. It was discussing how to interface with the system. The code I used is as follows.

The script comes from Lady ada in her post on hacking the connect.
I would love get this working. I am using python

This is a link to that code

http://learn.adafruit.com/hacking-the-kinect/fuzzing

The errors I get are as follow

```
sudo python UsbFuzzer.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UsbFuzzer.py", line 14, in <module>
    dev.set_configuration()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 554, in set_configuration
    self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 92, in managed_set_configuration
    self.backend.set_configuration(self.handle, cfg.bConfigurationValue)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 503, in set_configuration
    _check(_lib.libusb_set_configuration(dev_handle, config_value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 403, in _check
    raise USBError(_str_error[ret], ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 16] Resource busy
```

Comment: You shouldn't just say the code comes from Lady Ada, you should provide a link.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Did you check with the code author it was okay to repost the code here? By posting a complete piece of code here, you are effectively relicensing it under the CC-Wiki license used by Stack Overflow. If you are not the author and do not have permission, please do remove it.

Comment: The Change has been made

Comment: @DavidGrayson Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that libusb is returning an error code, "Resource busy".  This could be a permissions problem.  Try running your program with sudo and see if that fixes it.  This link looks promising, because it talks about how to set up a udev rule so you don't have to run as root:

[pyusb: cannot set configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218683/pyusb-cannot-set-configuration)

If that does not help, you could Google around for "libusb resource busy".